# Recently added data on mysql not showing up after I call inner join

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this issue, I add an information to the database and it doesn't show up when I do an inner join on two of my tables until like after two mins of after adding the data. I can't seem to really figure out why thus is happening. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Here is a sample of what I am doing using node mysql

```
var currentTime = Date.now();
var pastOneDay  = currentTime - config.justADay;

var query       = "SELECT * FROM ?? INNER JOIN ?? ON ??=?? WHERE ??=? AND ?? < ? ORDER BY ?? + 0 LIMIT ?";
var table       = ["following", "posts", "following.followed_username", "posts.username", "following.username", usersname, "posts.initial_time_posted", pastOneDay, "posts.initial_time_posted", config.noOfPostsToSend];

query           = mysql.format(query, table);

connection.query(query, function(err, postsReturned) {
    if(err) {
        callback(true, null);
    } else {
        callback(false, postsReturned);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code above looks OK. You'll need to give more info. How are you adding information to the database? What specific records are you adding? If you don't use Javascript, and just execute SQL directly to add data then retrieve it (with joins) does it work? If so, find out what exact SQL your javascript code ends up using, and see what the differences are. At the moment there's not enough info to help you.

Comment: Apparently I only execute javascript to add data to the database, then as soon as data is inserted I want to refresh users view with most updated data as well by joining two tables together, but it doesnt show up until after 2 mins.